# How can I use sprintf to change a number in a string?

Tags: c, string, printf

I want to change the number in a particular string. For example, if I had the string "GenLabel2", I want to change that to "GenLabel0". The solution I am looking for doesn't just simply change the character from 2 to 0, but rather uses an arithmetic approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "an arithmetic approach"? Can you provide an example transformation?

Comment: Something along these Lines:

char* label="genLabel2";
char* label2= label[7]-2; Therefore Label2 is now "genLabel0"

Comment: Never mind I got it using an approach similar to above, but I'd still like to know other methods of doing such.

Comment: what is so special about this `arithmetic approach`?

Answer (score 1):

This method works with numbers larger than 9. It takes the rightmost number in the string, and adds an arbitrary number to it (which is read in from the command line). The number in the string is assumed to be positive.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LABEL_MAX 4096

char *find_last_num(char *str, size_t size)
{
    char *num_start = (char *)NULL;
    char *s;

    /* find the start of the last group of numbers */
    for (s = str + size - 1; s != str; --s)
    {
        if (isdigit(*s))
            num_start = s;
        else if (num_start)
            break; /* we found the entire number */
    }
    return num_start;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char label[LABEL_MAX] = "GenLabel2";
    size_t label_size;
    int delta_num;
    char *num_start;
    int num;
    char s_num[LABEL_MAX];

    /* check args */
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s delta_num\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    delta_num = atoi(argv[1]);

    /* find the number */
    label_size = strlen(label);
    num_start = find_last_num(label, label_size);

    /* handle case where no number is found */
    if (!num_start)
    {
        printf("No number found!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    num = atoi(num_start);     /* get num from string */
    *num_start = '\0';         /* trim num off of string */
    num += delta_num;          /* change num using cl args */
    sprintf(s_num, "%d", num); /* convert num to string */
    strncat(label, s_num, LABEL_MAX - label_size - 1); /* append num back to string */
    label[LABEL_MAX - 1] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", label);

    return 0;
}
```